# Android Thread.start() CalledFromWrongThreadException

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am not sure if my understating is correct because I am not getting the expected output. I have a class within which I am calling a method that is supposed to start a thread.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
beginListenForData()
}
```

The  beginListenForData function is to start a thread and check at times if data is there for reading. If that's the case, it reads and updates a UI variable :

```
void beginListenForData()
{
    Thread workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {    
            int bytesAvailable = 3;
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            {
                try
                {
                    bytesAvailable = mmInStream.available();
                    if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        mmInStream.read(packetBytes);
                bytesAvailable = mmInStream.available();
                String s = new String(packetBytes);
                text.setText(s);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

       workerThread.start();
   }

}
```

I am not getting the desired output. That thread should read the data or check if the data is available. If available then read it and set a UI variable to the values read.

Am I doing the implementation correctly? Do I have something wrong in my code?

Comment: use async thread instead

Comment: I am new to JAVA - how do we create that type of thread?

Comment: You cannot update the UI from a background `Thread`. The `Main Thread` must do all the updates. So in order to do this you will have to use a `Handler` to pass `Message`s between your Background `Thread` and your `Main Thread`.

Comment: so, what do you get instead of desired output?

Comment: The initial data is displayed in UI which was sent the first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread can't update GUI
You can use `runOnUiThread()` method or use `Handler`

**EDIT :** example of Handler : *[How to use an Android Handler to update a TextView in the UI Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685752/how-to-use-an-android-handler-to-update-a-textview-in-the-ui-thread)*

Comment: Where do I write the handler?

Comment: You have to create a `Class` that `extends Thread` check out this post i put from yesterday which shows how to. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671923/using-thread-handler-looper-for-worker-thread-android/22697875#22697875

Comment: I've just added a link for an example of Handlers

Comment: Thanks your referral link to the example made me to solve the issue. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 4):

A normal `Thread` [should not access the UI thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads). I would advise using an `AsyncTask` instead of using standard Threads or Runnables in Android. An `AsyncTask` can be used to both simultaneously work away from the UI thread, and then make changes to it. Everything called in the `doInBackground()` method is done away from the main UI thread, and everything called in the `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` methods can interact nicely with your UI.

An `AsyncTask` is recommended when your calling a new thread from something running on the UI Thread (like an `Activity`, as in your instance). Example below;

```
public class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        // Work to be done in the background.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Changes to be made to UI
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
         // Changes to be made to UI
    }

}
```

Then you can just run the `AysncTask` from your activity like so;

```
new YourAsyncTask().execute("");
```

To work on your `Activity`, you may need to create a custom constructor for your `AysncTask` and pass your activity instance to it through the constructor, to be stored in an instance variable. I hope this helps.

Further Information;

- [When to use an AsyncTask vs Handler vs Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964011/handler-vs-asynctask-vs-thread)

Answer (score 2):

```
 text.setText(s);
```

you can not touch the UI from your working thread. It should be the UI Thread that execute   `text.setText(s);`

Comment: Do I need to create another thread in my class to update the UI - if so how do I get the data read from the thread?

Answer (score 0):

So here is how i would do this

create member variables of your activity:

```
private BackgroundWorkerThread m_bgThread = null;
protected Handler m_bgHandler = null;
```

See below my BackgroundWorkerThread class and then to initialize the thread and handler in your main activity in onCreate():

```
  // Notice we pass the Handler Constructor this because we are implementing the interface
  // in our activity
  m_bgHandler = new Handler(this)
  m_bgThread = new BackgroudnWorkerThread();
  m_bgThread.start();
```

make sure you have your activity `implements Handler.Callback` interface which will add this method to your Activity:

```
@Override public boolean handleMessage(Message msg)
 {
     switch(msg.what){

     case 0:
          // Will update the UI on the Main Thread
          updateUI(msg.obj);
      break;

     case 1:
         // rejoin the Thread with the main Thread
        try {
           m_bgThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      break;
   }
    return true;
 }
```

inside each case statement is where you do message passing to the background thread.

for example calling sendFirstMessage() somewhere in your activity:

```
 public void sendFirstMessage(){

    // Passes the 0 to the background Handler handleMessage
    m_bgThread.workerHandler.obtainMessage(0).sendToTarget();

 }
```

So then in your Activity's handler handleMessage() override

```
 case 0:
     updateUI(msg.obj);

 break;
```

and then

```
public void updateUI(Object obj){

    text.setText(obj.toString());

    // Call to tell Background Thread to shut down looper
    m_bgThread.workerHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();

    // Call to tell the Main Thread no more updates needed
    m_bgHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();
```

}

Then create your background thread class as a child class of your activity:

```
private class BackgroundWorkerThread extends Thread implements Handler.Callback{
  private Looper workerLooper;
  protected Handler workerHandler;

 @Override public void run()
 {
     // Set up the Handler and Looper
     Looper.prepare();
     workerLooper = Looper.myLooper();
     workerHandler = new Handler(workerLooper, this);
     Looper.loop();
 }

 @Override public boolean handleMessage(Message msg)
 {
     switch(msg.what){

     case 0:
         // now this function is being called to run on the background Thread  
      beginListenForData();
      break;

     case 1:
      workerLooper.quit();
      break;
   }
    return true;
 }

}


  // This method is now being execute in the background
 public void beginListenForData()
 {

           int bytesAvailable = 3;
          while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
          {
            try{
                bytesAvailable = mmInStream.available();
                if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                {
                byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                mmInStream.read(packetBytes);
                bytesAvailable = mmInStream.available();
                String s = new String(packetBytes);
                // Instead of trying to set the text view here, send a message back to 
                // the Activity to update the UI on the Main thread
                // text.setText(s);
                // Passes 0, and the String Object to the Activity Handler
                 m_bgHandler.obtainMessage(0, s).sendToTarget();
                }
        }catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
  }
```

This is a little difficult to wrap your head around but this is how its done, manually creating a thread, using a looper to check for messages in the background, and then passing messages to the activity from the background thread to Update the UI.

Good Luck! any questions feel free to ask.

Or you could take the easiest route possible ideology taken from http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html

```
 public void beginListenForData()
  {
   String s = null;

   new Thread(new Runnable(){

      public void run(){

           int bytesAvailable = 3;
          while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
          {
            try{
                bytesAvailable = mmInStream.available();
                if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                {
                  byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                  mmInStream.read(packetBytes);
                  bytesAvailable = mmInStream.available();
                  s = new String(packetBytes);

                   // Takes Care of updating the UI
                   text.post(new Runnable(){
                       public void run(){
                           text.setText(s);
                       }
                    });
                }
             }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
       }
     }).start();
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` first ?

Then you have to call `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);`.

Why `bytesAvailable` is set to 3 and not 0 ?

Why `bytesAvailable = mmInStream.available();` is call twice ? Only one is enough !

Then are `mmInStream` and `text` ( !important! `text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thetextviewid);`) initialised somewhere ?

If all of these things are done, everything should be ok.

EDIT: at the end you **have** to call `text.postInvalidate();`

Comment: `postInvalidate();` instead of `invalidate();` is here to update views from non-ui thread like said here :  [View | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate())

Comment: It may be technically possible but the android documents specifically insist that it isn't done this way - "*[do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads)*"